# React: How to add Textfield in Selects using Material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How I add Textfield in Selects(Select Menu) using Material-UI ?

I try to search it, but I did not earn much.

How can I do?

I tried it out, but there was a problem with the css.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/ component with `multiline` props

Something like

```
<TextField
    id="standard-textarea"
    label="With placeholder multiline"
    placeholder="Placeholder"
    multiline
    margin="normal"
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the other answer doesn't really answer the question, I figured I'd share my insights.

I'm basically trying to create something similar to what you see in Google Calendar's time inputs, where you get a list of pre-defined times at convenient 30 min intervals, but you can also type in a custom time:

[image: GCal time picker]

Unfortunately, scouring through the Material UI docs and GitHub issues, I don't believe there's anything built-in to accomplish this. You will have to have separate `<TextField/>` and `<Menu/>` components, and link them together manually. Have the `<Menu/>` anchored below the `<TextField/>`, and any time it changes, have it update the `<TextField/>`, which will serve as the main state.